# How to get the amount of digits after the decimal point

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

How can I easily find the amount of digits after the decimal point?
For example:

```
0.2 would result 1 (1 digit after the point)
0.09 would result 2 (2 digits after the point)
0.641 would result 3 (3 digits after the point)
```

I think this is fairly simple, but I just can't get my head around it right now...

Thanks!

Comment: count them? how is this calculus?

Comment: do you want to do it algorithmically, like in a computer progamme?

Comment: I've no idea in which category to put it. It's fairly basic I know, and I know I learned it in school like 20 years ago. But I just can't remember it.
And "counting" is not an answer. it was some kind of formula I could use...

Comment: @danimal yes exactly.

Comment: BTW, I know it's easy to do like putting it in a string, then searching for the "." and subtracting it from the total strings length. But I thought I could do it via normal mathematical formulas to speed things up. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on just how you store your number.

If you are storing it as a rational number or as a fraction $\frac ab$ in lowest terms, or if you have a routine to convert your number to this format, here is how you can do it.

Find the prime factorization of $b$. Let's say it is

$$b=2^r5^sp^t\ldots$$

If $b$ has a prime factor other than $2$ or $5$, the number of decimal places is infinite. Otherwise, the number of decimal places in $\frac ab$ is

$$\max(r,s)$$

Do you need an explanation of why this works?

---

If your number $x$ is a float or a real number, find the smallest $t$ such that

$$10^t\cdot x=\lfloor 10^t\cdot x \rfloor$$

(The brackets are the greatest integer function.) Then $t$ is the number of decimal places. If no such $t$ exists, the number of decimal places is infinite.